# Unable to change the widget for a webform coponent

Tags: webforms

When editing a webform component (7.x-4.23) selecting a different widget type (e.g. from email to hidden) has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling module Hide Submit Button (7.x-2.4) restored the webform functionality.